# Where to flash oxygen 12 image files over fastboot?

Tags: rom-flashing, fastboot, oxygenos, oneplus

I managed to brick my phone (OnePlus Nord CE 5G) to the point where I can only get into fastboot and fastbootd. I was using oxygen 12 previously so I believe flashing 11 is not possible.

I was able to extract all the images from the latest oxygen 12 image found [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/oneplus-nord-ce-rom-ota-oxygen-os-repo-of-oxygen-os-builds.4326661/) for my phone using payload_dumper, but I can't figure out where to flash all the images to. I've googled around a fair bit but I can't find any specific instructions for this device/update.

My best guess is the script below. All the steps are successfull but I'm still left with an unbootable device.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
#!/bin/env bash

# This script assumes all .img files are in a folder called images

# Wipe entire device
fastboot -w

# Images that should be flashed in bootloader mode
# (Said someone on the internet)
fastboot flash boot images/boot.img
fastboot flash dtbo images/dtbo.img
fastboot flash modem images/modem.img
fastboot flash recovery images/recovery.img
fastboot flash vbmeta images/vbmeta.img
fastboot flash vbmeta_system images/vbmeta_system.img

# Reboot to FastbootD mode
fastboot reboot fastboot

# .img files where the name corresponds to a partition name
fastboot flash --slot=all abl images/abl.img
fastboot flash --slot=all aop images/aop.img
fastboot flash --slot=all bluetooth images/bluetooth.img
fastboot flash --slot=all devcfg images/devcfg.img
fastboot flash --slot=all dsp images/dsp.img
fastboot flash --slot=all featenabler images/featenabler.img
fastboot flash --slot=all hyp images/hyp.img
fastboot flash --slot=all imagefv images/imagefv.img
fastboot flash --slot=all keymaster images/keymaster.img
fastboot flash --slot=all oplusstanvbk images/oplusstanvbk.img
fastboot flash --slot=all qupfw images/qupfw.img
fastboot flash --slot=all tz images/tz.img
fastboot flash --slot=all uefisecapp images/uefisecapp.img
fastboot flash --slot=all xbl images/xbl.img
fastboot flash --slot=all xbl_config images/xbl_config.img

# I'm fairly confident these all go to the super partition
# Less confident about "odm" and "system_ext"
fastboot flash --slot=all super images/odm.img
fastboot flash --slot=all super images/system.img
fastboot flash --slot=all super images/vendor.img
fastboot flash --slot=all super images/product.img
fastboot flash --slot=all super images/system_ext.img

# No clue about these but I can't imagine where else they would go.
# I also tried ignoring these, but no success
fastboot flash --slot=all super images/my_heytap.img
fastboot flash --slot=all super images/my_company.img
fastboot flash --slot=all super images/my_preload.img
fastboot flash --slot=all super images/my_stock.img
fastboot flash --slot=all super images/my_region.img
fastboot flash --slot=all super images/my_carrier.img
fastboot flash --slot=all super images/my_product.img
fastboot flash --slot=all super images/my_bigball.img
fastboot flash --slot=all super images/my_engineering.img
fastboot flash --slot=all super images/my_manifest.img

# All available images are flashed.
```

ps: I am using the latest version of fastboot.